# Related to Insertion in table

Tags: sql-server

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_InsertUpdateVehicleWheel
(
  @vehicleWheelId int,
  @vehicleWheelName varchar(20)
)
AS
    IF @vehicleWheelId = 0
       INSERT INTO VehicleWheel (VehicleWheelId, VehicleWheelName)
       VALUES (@vehicleWheelId, @vehicleWheelName)
    else 
       UPDATE VehicleWheel 
       SET VehicleWheelName = @vehicleWheelName
       WHERE VehicleWheelId = @vehicleWheelId

    RETURN----------
```

When I want  to insert into table (`VehicleWheel`) containing attributes

1. `VehicleWheelId int`
2. `VehicleWheelName varchar(20))`

where `Id` is autogenerated and I want  to insert name, then an error occurs:

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table
>   'VehicleWheel' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

plz send me the reply how I overcome this error...

Thanking you.......

Answer (score 3):

The error clearly says what's wrong (IDENTITY column VehicleID in the INSERT columns list)...

Change the insert statement to:

```
Insert into VehicleWheel (VehicleWheelName) values (@vehicleWheelName)
```

So the SP would now be:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_InsertUpdateVehicleWheel
(
    @vehicleWheelId int,
    @vehicleWheelName varchar(20)
)

AS

    if @vehicleWheelId=0
            INSERT INTO VehicleWheel (VehicleWheelName) VALUES (@vehicleWheelName)
    ELSE 
    Update VehicleWheel set
    VehicleWheelName = @vehicleWheelName
    where VehicleWheelId = @vehicleWheelId
    RETURN----------
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set IDENTITY INSERT to ON, I don't know, it feels like the error is obvious

you can do this using this:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT table ON
```

where table is your table